# Youtube API-Video upload stop working and how do I solve?

Tags: php, api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I try to upload videos using php.The problem is after this loop:

```
// Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
$status = false;
$handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
    $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
    $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
 }
```

I have tried this way but I still have some bugs. But I don't know where went wrong

```
$media = new \Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
   $client,
   $insertRequest,
   'video/*',
   file_get_contents($pathToFile),  <== put file content instead of null
   true,
   $chunkSizeBytes
);
$media->setFileSize($size);

$status = false;
while (!$status) {
   $status = $media->nextChunk();
}
```

And appeared following wrong

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0bnP.png]

following is my code
index.php

```
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
            <?php echo (!empty($errorMsg))?'<p class="err-msg">'.$errorMsg.'</p>':''; ?>
            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" value="" />
            <label for="description">Description:</label>
            <textarea name="description" cols="20" rows="2" ></textarea>
            <label for="tags">Tags:</label>
            <input type="text" name="tags" value="" />
            
            <label for="tags">Privacy:</label>
            <select name="privacy">
                <option value="public">Public</option>
                <option value="private">Private</option>
            </select>
            <label for="file">Choose Video File:</label> <input type="file" name="file" >
            <input name="videoSubmit" type="submit" value="Upload">
```

upload video part

```
if(isset($_POST['videoSubmit'])){
    // Video info
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $desc = $_POST['description'];
    $tags = $_POST['tags'];
    $privacy = !empty($_POST['privacy'])?$_POST['privacy']:'public';
    print($_FILES);
    // Check whether file field is not empty
    if($_FILES["file"]["name"] != ''){
        // File upload path
        $fileName = str_shuffle('codexworld').'-'.basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $filePath = "videos/".$fileName;
```

In the above code, it can't get the `videoSubmit` and `file`

Comment: Does your file `$pathToFile` really exist?

Comment: I find that nothing in my `$pathToFile`.I don't know why it catches nothing

Comment: Then that is your problem: `$pathToFile` has to be the complete path to the video file that you want uploaded to YouTube.

Comment: thanks, but I find another thing that it can not get by video info, Besides, the info can't insert into the database, so the filename and path always are empty.  Below is my code.

Comment: Sorry, but don't quite understand your comment; my question: does your video content (that you want to be uploaded) come from a file residing on your computer?

Comment: Yes, the video I want to upload is residing on my computer.

Comment: Then that video has a path that identifies it within your compyter. That path should be assigned to `$pathToFile`.

Comment: ok, I will try to change. But why `$size` is undefined

Comment: To `$size` should be assigned the length of the file `$pathToFile`. Suffices to have something like `$size = filesize($pathToFile)`, or even only `$media->setFileSize(filesize($pathToFile))` if `$size` is not used somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you sir, I will try it.